# Replace question mark in URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, filenames, urlencode

I have some files that exist under a directory and its name contains a question mark.

I'm trying to replace the `?` with `%3F` (URL encoded `?`) but I get a "404 Not Found" response. Numbers in the URL are dynamic.

What I have:

```
https://www.example.com/uploads/10015015?afe/filename.doc
```

What I need:

```
https://www.example.com/uploads/10015015%3Fafe/filename.doc
```

This is the rule I added in `.htaccess` but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?afe([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /$1%3F%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
```

Comment: `QUERY_STRING` contains the question mark, as your own regex tests. You then embed this after `%3F`. Seems one question mark too many, no?

Comment: @deceze Although the `QUERY_STRING` server var does _not_ contain the question mark, which is _part_ of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?afe([^&]*)
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
> RewriteRule (.*) /$1%3F%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
> ```

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable does not contain the `?` itself (query string *delimiter*). However, the regex `^?afe([^&]*)` is entirely invalid (the `?` is a regex quantifier and `^` is not quantifiable) so this would/should result in a 500 Internal Server Error since the regex cannot be *compiled*. (Although you say you are getting a 404, so is this rule even being processed?!)

There's no need to check that the query string is not empty (second *condition*) when you have already established that there is a query string that matches the pattern (in the first *condition*).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^afe/[^&]+\.doc$
RewriteRule ^(uploads/.+) $1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,QSD,L]
```

Note that the `%` before `3` must be backslash-escaped to avoid it being treated as a numeric backreference (which would otherwise be empty).

I removed the slash prefix on the *substitution* string so it would be treated as a relative file-path, as opposed to a URL-path (unless you have a `RewriteBase` directive set).

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is the preferred way to *discard* the original query string from the request on Apache 2.4, rather than appending an empty query string (trailing `?`) which would have been required on earlier versions of Apache.

Comment: Thanks. I can download the files now but the problem is the files are named with the numbers string. E.g: https://www.example.com/uploads/10015015?afe/filename.doc 
The downloaded file is renamed as 10015015.doc instead filename.doc

Comment: @lccv If you are downloading this to a Windows machine then `?` is not a permitted character in Windows filenames (a limitation of the OS). To control the default filename  you would need to replace the `?` with some other character and use this in the  `filename` field of the `Content-Disposition` header as the file is downloaded.

Comment: The file name would be the result of the browser still effectively seeing a query string. To avoid that, you could redirect to a different URL externally first - say, `/uploads/10015015_afe/filename.doc` - and then rewrite that to the question mark version for file system access again, internally. (But in that case, I would rather rename the folder to begin with - and then at most rewrite old external links, that still use the old version.)